# Java REST Web Service shows 404

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, http-status-code-404

I have created a RESTful app with Jersey and deployed in Apache Tomcat.

I get a 404 when I try to access the service.

My `web.xml` is:

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>         
    <init-param>  
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>  
      <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  

  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My code is:

```
@Path("/countries")  
public class SolrLogService {
@Context ServletContext context;

@GET  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
public List<Countries> getCountries()  
{  
    List<Countries> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Countries>();  
    listOfCountries=createCountryList();  
    return listOfCountries;  
}  


@GET  
@Path("{id: \\d+}")  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
 public Countries getCountryById(@PathParam("id") int id)  
 {  
  List<Countries> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Countries>();  
  listOfCountries=createCountryList();  

  for (Countries country: listOfCountries) {  
   if(country.getId()==id)  
    return country;  
  }  
  return null;  

 }
```

When I try to access the following

http://localhost:8080/LogEngine/rest/countries

it shows:

```
type Status report

message Not Found

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't configured the Jersey servlet with any resources. Most of time you'll just want it to scan you packages for the resource. To do that you can simply do

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>         
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.foo.myresources,org.bar.otherresources
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>
```

where `org.foo.myresources,org.bar.otherresources` are two comma separated packages where your resource classes are located.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET
@Path("AllCountries")  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
public List<Countries> getCountries()  {  
    List<Countries> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Countries>();  
    listOfCountries=createCountryList();  
    return listOfCountries;  
}
```

include a path annotation in the function returning the list of countries and change your URL to look like this 
http://localhost:8080/LogEngine/rest/countries/AllCountries

Answer (score 0):

`@Path` annotation is not mandatory if there is only one `@GET`. Could be that you need your request to accept JSON. So either add the Accept request header and set it to Application/JSON or change in the code produces TEXT and see if it works